# my question was marked as duplicate but it is 2 months older

Tags: support

[How can I install Intel HD Graphics proprietary drivers on elementary OS?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/10/how-can-i-install-intel-hd-graphics-proprietary-drivers-on-elementary?noredirect=1#comment4232_10)

[How do I install the latest Intel Linux Graphics?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/1734/how-do-i-install-the-latest-intel-linux-graphics)

why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which question is a duplicate is not typically a question of which is older, but more typically which one contains more information, both in itself and in it's answers.

Comment: It should be noted that in this specific case, the answers to your question are out of date, while the other still holds true.